# Degree modulo 2 and usual degree

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If $f:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is a map, why do we get its $\mathbf{Z}_2$-degree by taking its $\mathbf{Z}$-degree modulo 2? I am taking the definition of degree via homology theory

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ degree? If your definition is the induced map $f_*\colon H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, then the answer is universal coefficients. Otherwise, the answer may be different.

Comment: yes, thanks! please consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expanded answer to my comment above:

If you take your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_2$-degree to be the induced map $f_*:H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, then the answer is the Universal Coefficients Theorem for homology. The theorem states that the sequence
$$ 0\to H_*(X;\mathbb{Z})\otimes G\to H_*(X;G)\to\mathrm{Tor}(H_{*-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}),G)\to 0 $$
is always (split) exact. Taking $*=2$, $X=S^n$, and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$, we get the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_*(S^n;\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{Z}_2 @>f_*\otimes 1>> H_*(S^n;\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{Z}_2\\
@VVV @VVV \\
H_*(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2) @>f_*>> H_*(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)
\end{CD}
$$
The vertical arrows are isomorphisms from the Universal Coefficients Theorem. Finally, the functoriality of taking Homology gives that the diagram is commutative.

Comment: I think you are missing a couple of $\otimes \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @M.B. You're absolutely correct. It's fixed now